# Generate small cubes on a Plane?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script where with mouse click and drag, it generates small cubes in the scene view. However, I have a plane and I want to generate these cubes exactly on top of this plane. Is there any way I can achieve this?

```cs
public class SmallCubes : MonoBehaviour
{
    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit hit;
    public GameObject prefab;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, hit.point.z), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What isnt working about your script?

Comment: I want to generates these cubes on top of a plane. Like writing it on piece of paper type.

Comment: that didnt answer the question :P  What exactly isnt working about the script you have

Comment: The script is working perfectly. I am able to generate cubes anywhere I click.

Comment: So whats the question then.. if the script works perfectly ..

Comment: Please read the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the plane's y position to instantiate instead of the hit point.

```
GameObject plane = GameObject.Find("plane");

GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(hit.point.x, plane.transform.position.y + cubesize/2, hit.point.z), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Though I'm with the other commenters, it seems like this code would do exactly what you want already.